# how install libnginx-mod-http-passenger on xenial 16.04 : has no installation candidate

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

What I tried to install my nginx + passenger for rails app : (**works fine for debian stretch** on my other server)

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
```

=>

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx 
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx
```

and :

```
sudo cd /tmp; sudo wget http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key; sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key
sudo apt-get install -y dirmngr gnupg
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger xenial main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras passenger libnginx-mod-http-passenger
```

but I have an errror :

> Package libnginx-mod-http-passenger is not available, but is referred
>   to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has
>   been obsoleted, or is only available from another source However the
>   following packages replace it:   passenger:i386 passenger
>
> E: Package 'libnginx-mod-http-passenger' has no installation candidate

I need it to my Rails app using passenger, so **how can I install libnginx-mod-http-passenger on my Xubuntu 16.04 ?**

thx

Comment: libnginx-mod-http-passenger is referenced as passenger:i386 so, i think you try to install x86 on x64 mixing is not fine

Comment: @djdomi I dont understand where I select x86?! I use same command for my other server (debian x64 bit) and it works fine, so where it's wrong? thx.